# finding convergence of the arithmetic mean

Tags: analysis, arithmetic

Let $\{x_n\}$ converge. Prove that the arithmetic mean: $s_n = \sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{x_n}{n}$ converges.

I am aware of the previous solutions for this exercise presented on this website, but don't know why this approach won't work:

If $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$, there exists some $N$ such that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$. Then,

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{k=1}|x_k - x| < (\frac{1}{n})(n)(\epsilon) = \epsilon$$ for $n > N$.

Is it because there would be no defined value if $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I apologize in advance if this question seems silly. I'm still trying to get used to the "flavor" of analysis.

Comment: $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for $\color{red}{n>N}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the estimate:
$$
\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k-x| < \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) n \epsilon < \epsilon
$$
You are doing this because you think that each term $|x_k - x| < \epsilon$, for $1 \leq k \leq n$, and there are $n$ such terms.

However, you know this only when $n > N$! So you cannot assume that $|x_k - x| < \epsilon$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Comment: If you are aware of the method used to solve this question, then you should keep that in mind, because it is going to appear over and over in various disguised forms when you look at more series, and further mathematics.